# Confusion about lambda syntax

Tags: c#, lambda, ienumerable

I have a product class and stores some information like id,name,price .I am wondering that how can  get values using lambda syntax for example bigger or smaller than 1000  .

this is my Product class

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
     public class product 
     {
         public double fiyat { get; set; }
         public string ad { get; set; }
         public  int id { get; set; }

         public product(int ids, string ads, double fiyats) 
         {
             id = ids;
             ad = ads;
             fiyat = fiyats;
         }

         public static List<product> getProdcts() 
         {
             List<product> list = new List<product>();
             product[] p = new product[] 
             { 
                 new product(1,"Monitör",1200),
                 new product(2,"Klavye",180),
                 new product(3,"Mouse",75),
                 new product(4,"Laptop",2000),
                 new product(5,"Masa",400)
             };

             list.AddRange(p);
             return list;
         }
     }

     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             List<product> p = product.getProdcts();
             /// IEnumerable<product> queryObj = from item in p where item.Fiyat > 1000   select item;
             IEnumerable<product> quobj =.....
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by '**bigger or smaller than 1000**'?

Comment: Your code was very cluttered. Please pay attention to presenting us your code formatted more carefully. This time I've done it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use lambda in place of LINQ, you can do it in the following way (which BTW is partially LINQ anyway):

```
IEnumerable<product> result = p.Where((item) => item.fiyat > 1000);
```